# Which hardware acceleration suitable for ffmpeg video encoding job?

Tags: video, high-end

I want to transcode live stream video for 200 channels (24/7 work) with ffmpeg. Now I use Intel Quicksync it's work very well for not over 10 channels transcoding. I'm going to buy "11GB GDDR6 RTX2080Ti INNO3D Twin X2" with 4352 "CUDA Core".

Please suggest me that this card is the right choice for my job or not.

My OS is Windows 10 / Windows server 2016

Comment: I think Nvidia card only have a limited set of encoding hardware, since they are still tuned to be used in a desktop environment where they'd be encoding one or two streams maximum. You really should look at dedicated hardware for that, maybe something like Tesla, Quadro or even FPGA.
You should search for h264 hardware encoder. Also take a look at this answer, it might be helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/66208/hardware-h-264-video-encoders-for-production-use

Comment: It really depends also if they're okay with the results that hardware encoding gives. NVENC has gotten a lot better, but it's still not as configurable as a software encoder. Do you have a target bitrate/reference quality?

Comment: @JMY1000 I will encode from 2-6Mbps to 1.2 Mbps 200 Channels. How different between NVENC and CUDA (in hardware issue)